# Case Class from Parquet using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have worked through some example code, on how to store data in a parquet file and implemented it pretty much as shown in the [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files):

```
val schema = StructType(
  List(StructField("id", LongType, false), StructField("values", ArrayType(FloatType), false))
)
val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).saveAsParquetFile("file.parquet")
```

When reading the parquet file, I use

```
sqlContext.parquetFile("file.parquet")
```

The examples in the programming guide always assume that you work with strings, and therefore the following works pretty straight forward:

```
data.map(t => "Name: " + t(0)).collect().foreach(println)
```

However, as you can see in my schema definition, I work with a float array. Of course, I could parse the string to a float array myself, but it doesn't seem to be way of doing it. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row` returns an `Any` when used with the base indexer, so you should be able to just use `t.getSeq[Float](0)` and it will return your data as a `Seq[Float]`. You can also use `printSchema` on your `DataFrame` to verify that the type is indeed an `ArrayType`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just for the sake of completeness, this is what I do: `sqlContext.parquetFile("file.parquet").map(x => x.getSeq[Float](1))`. Note that in `getSeq(n)` the `n` specifies the field(number)